# Remove bottom Navigation when navigate to new Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

i have bottom Navigation, i navigate new Fragment from bottom click but Bottom Navigation is not removed to the new fragment

navigate new fragment

```
edit_flow.setOnClickListener {

            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_flowFragment)

}
```

i want to remove the bottom Navigation when launching FlowFragment

[image: see the image]

Comment: simple way is that on navigation icon click start new activity instead of using fragment. either you can setVisibility(View.GONE) of navigation view on click of any item. Why this is happening because frameLayout will be above navigationview and in framelayout we are replacing just fragment so at bottom navigation view will always visible.

Comment: Thank you where i but setVisibility(View.GONE) sorry i'm new to android development

Comment: setVisibility(View.GONE) on click of navigation item click. For example from above image, "Deep Link" is one of navigation item right? so, you can get onClick method of that "Deep Link", in onClick method write like your_navtigation_view_id.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: Ok it works but Navigation View is not visible when i come back to Home Fragment

Comment: Obviously it will not show because once you hide it in onClick of "Deep Link". now again you need to set your_navtigation_view_id.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) in onClick method of "Home" item of navigation view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the Host Activity, after bind NavControler, Try this:

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.yourFragment-> bottomNavigationMain.visibility = View.GONE
                .
                .
                .
            else -> bottomNavigationMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

in here. yourFragment should not show ButtonNavigationMenu. the other fragments will have it visible.

Comment: I am glad it helps you.